# Empty non-empty file

Tags: windows, file-recovery

Yesterday I was working on one file, it worked great! Today, I tried to open this same file, but it is now empty. Even when I try to open it with Notepad, the file is completely empty. If I look at the properties, I see that it is 11kB. How could it be empty? It is really bothering me, this was a very important file...

I don't think it is relevant, but it is a .cpp file. If I try to open it with Visual Studio, then Visual Studio opens the Notepad with nothing in it.

Does anyone know how to recover the content?

Comment: More information please. I assume you mean KB, not KO. What type of file is it (in Windows the file extension)? What do you mean, "cannot do it"? Do you receive an error? What error?

Comment: I've modified the question.

Comment: My guess is that there's a character that Notepad recognizes as "end of file" somewhere near the beginning of the file.  You need to look at it with a hex editor such as [Neo](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor).

Comment: It says 00 everywhere... I guess the content of my file is lost then.